# TypeScript - class dictionary generic that holds other generic types - problem with generic types being lost inside method

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a semi-complex example where there's a class `Store` that has a dictionary of other "value classes" (`Alpha<AlphaVal>`, `Beta<BetaVal>`) as its generic parameter and it has a `get` method that returns values from that dictionary (values held by "value classes").

I could create the types for the return value of `get` and it works properly. However, I have a problem with what happens inside `get`.

For some reason, the generic of these value classes is lost. It is especially lost when using a custom type predicate to narrow the type, but I think the issue is not with just the custom type guard, but what that the union type of `entry` inside `get` method has already lost the generics.

What do you think, is it a bug or is there a valid reason it works the way it works? If it's the latter, is there a way to modify the custom type guard `isAlpha` to preserve the generic type?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=true#code/PTAECEEMGcFNQC4E8AOtqgGYHsBOoA3SAGwFd4BjYmOaAKGTVAEFiUALSANRNAF5QAb1ABtAJYA7ACawAHgC5Q0BLkkBzALqLIEpAF8A3KAap44WAm68BE0gFsARrHwAfJSvWg3D7NmKwdAzo6EFAeMkpqaAwAWlB2PykMSEIScjoqGhY2TgAeABVQOQRYaQxWDitiAD4hOlBQFFUiEtSIxXyghpRSB2IxClAxaArOAAoASiEGvXrG3v7BtQtJjuncC1JcCUR2YYA6IgijWdmMqIxzSwKi2RKyiAsq2sE5prEW%20CPyDq75voGQ2gV0gk2mhjeC0BywQq1AhWEGwQWx2CD20EOaXgp2CoUY8GYIxykAKtQEAFE7rhIBQEAUADTZSq5UbPapBfEsInM-Jk%20G3e5JJl5SSYZygABKtQA-KBKSoaXT8ozWbkpbVFPLqbSGcKSazwtV2biwPl2PBOWpSJBcFIMtgJMogaz%20KBclwBaUhaqDSRam4QbkQYbqmM5t9YIouHQJooI0CuaquGSXnMGkiUaAxvHJModBRYNhMHqJkEzqEAMIOgjOBDlYlq2oIbCSxmBqWIFsSkxMcLkABiuGwdnJEhUSBuxS99eZvpqXke12DfrJc0KU4eqtF4qlc1lEtAaw3QsD2-wu4a%208PoFIEgA1hJsAB3CRBc5ZADKzY2uVHHnQnoPMI4jSHIijKKoEiaIoPrEoaC6Bsu856KmDTdM0kCtKU-4YAIwh6KAMBymOqjoG%20aGgKEADiFgYNhuBIG06QUT0AJLBYv4kUgACSUiAUKd6wEgRbEThoZphRRRcbxmrSXaFGxmEWKDsOf4MZxOEiGpPFSBoLyUWAGbbIgpigE%20eB3hgTTYGguDEEgEkUSAjlof4CBSeOrpogc9FiOgIj0TpGjkZJDRiMWYzDKyYyBRMUyvKFoWBfsUXEpMRihAAVqQTqlNAWyeGimG7BaplWjafHmbglkuaFblMfAAjJTC6W1ZJoRmvA1l9LAdjxM48DDLsxVoqVTBDbBlR9rA1RtU5YA6Hxo2gMsEjOICQ3ENgyiMtALZiAgADkGCPu5NBiGoEiQD1nYlaARk7BGc1oQ9DUhYlaGhCJFDYFscBKMOFh7FBoD9IJoBOFtT5mb9xCVRZjIOKQ7ncYdfXjoV2DPQ0oSYJIfG-e54UlRsx2ERDFglPgT6QEg%20zYwZ92bMZ8ZEdNKl2KygZqX50BaXJwVtWcH2hAAEs%20sA1rgjIHaAdi06Ap0U6A2VOjoQL5fAT4Hewd2WtatqI8jZk621oQJNDy2BSZ40YPifG5mIMh3Zgt60mIDr0yLYDccWwmkPE2BS6ADoeQx%20wtVMkPPjLR0YHA7nNkzyLGXOCFPOE9Jm2AsuQCgaA2nb5oraU62DJt23uZLpQm2ihM2-AV24EO2tQV7iWvc1KylsE3vwsXkhU%20gCCFcDagJkVRPuVVlmNEOtn2SHqLF69%20LtzMdBnJyH6QHYKD%20F%20eCNXUFGQDBDbCCUyiKCo5CgChEkOIogYAKyzWcP2Ou50C7-vsCHxsV0a1oYANgLkHee8D7fhmq1EIYB8QYFDq9eMM8542WcPZRkq0y4JiaOgZwNY7T1XjAIH%20kD-7QIjisQ6kBDqlmMEAA)

```
// Base types for value classes
type AlphaVal = { [index: string]: any}; 
type BetaVal = number | string | boolean;

// Value class - holds a value
class Alpha<T extends AlphaVal> {
  private value: T;
  public isAlpha() {  }
  public get(): T { return this.value; }
}

class Beta<T extends BetaVal> {
  private value: T;
  public isBeta() { };
  public get(): T { return this.value }
}

// type AsAlpha<T> = Extract<T, Alpha<AlphaVal>>;
type AsAlpha<T> = T extends Alpha<infer R>
  ? Extract<T, Alpha<R>> : Extract<T, Alpha<AlphaVal>>;

// The type guard
const isAlpha = <V extends Alpha<AlphaVal> | Beta<BetaVal>>(
  value: V
): value is AsAlpha<V> => {
    return (value instanceof Alpha);
}

// Converts Alpha<R> to R, Beta<R> to R
type ValueFromEntry<T extends Alpha<AlphaVal> | Beta<BetaVal>> =
  T extends Alpha<infer R>
  ? R : T extends Beta<infer R>
  ? R : unknown;

class Store<Entries extends { [index: string]: Alpha<AlphaVal> | Beta<BetaVal> }> {
    private entries = { } as Entries;

    // Gets entry value
    public get<EntryId extends keyof Entries>(
        entryId: EntryId
    ): ValueFromEntry<Entries[EntryId]> { // return type works properly
        //
        let entry = this.entries[entryId];

        if (isAlpha(entry)) {
            entry.isAlpha(); // just ensuring that the type guard works
            let value = entry.get();
            // The problem here is that the type is Alpha<AlphaValue>
            // and the generic is lost, so it's not assignable to the return value
            return value;

            // of course something like below would work, but I'm trying to
            // find out if there's a better way.
            // return value as ValueFromAlphaBeta<Entries[EntryId];
        }

        // However, it may not be just an issue with the type guard, but with
        // how the entry type is typed inside the function.
        // If you hover on entry.get() below, it's set to return AlphaVal | BetaVal,
        // it appears the generic is lost even without type narrowing.
        return entry.get();

        // The interesting thing is that it works properly on the return type.
    }
}

type SampleStore = {
    a: Alpha<{ test: true }>
    b: Beta<5>
}

const sampleStore = new Store<SampleStore>();

// types on return value work properly, generic is preserved
let value = sampleStore.get('a');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is complex but the core of the issue can be boiled down to something really simple.  When you check `if (isAlpha(entry))`, this narrows the type of the variable `entry`.  It does not narrow the type of the generic type parameter `EntryId`.

You cannot know that the entry type is `AlphaVal` and only `AlphaVal` because the type `EntryId` could be a broader type like `'alpha1' | 'alpha2' | 'beta1'` or even just `keyof Entries`.

Returning a value to a conditional return type is a problem for this reason even in the simplest of cases.  We we know that `value` is `true`, it doesn't *always* mean that `T extends true`.

```
const test = <T extends boolean>(value: T): T extends true ? "A" : "B" => {
    if ( value ) {
        return "A"; // error: Type '"A"' is not assignable to type 'T extends true ? "A" : "B"'
    } else {
        return "B"; // error: Type '"B"' is not assignable to type 'T extends true ? "A" : "B"'
    }
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF4YB4AqN4A8FgBMIYAjEEAG3gEMwA%20ACgDdqKBXeALhgwEpusufETgAnDjAD8MAEQBBGTG4yAQouR0YAbwCwAKBiGYASwBmMBjBbt4MXtv1GnMUfChtRYWQoDcMAPT%202KKiIKICAJ4ADrYA5PIysSbEYCCw1BAQxgDmYNQkVHAgcNFxgnjwhMRQ4rbSCUqyarGORgC%202BQQtroGzoau7p5NMn6BwaHhPKUw8c3JMKnpmTl5BbZQxVAzseXC1bVS3orKza2GbfptQA)

So yes you have to just assert correctness with `return value as ValueFromEntry<Entries[EntryId]>`.  Which you already know how to do, but hopefully you have a better understanding of why it's needed.